# Calling specific field on form.save() Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, modelform

I have a form where users can add videos to an event. When they submit, I want them to be redirected to the event page, but I'm having trouble figuring out the code necessary.

Here's my code:

views.py:

```
def add_video(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddVideo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            event = form.save()
            return redirect('event_detail', slug=event.slug)
    else: 
        form = AddVideo()
    return render(request, 'add_video.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^climbs/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.event_detail, name='event_detail'),
```

When I run this code, I keep getting an error that the Video model has no attribute slug. This attribute is found under the Event model. How do I pull the Event from the form and use the corresponding slug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whelp, as soon as I posted this I figured it out. Just had to change views.py to the following:

```
def add_video(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddVideo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            video = form.save()
            return redirect('event_detail', slug=video.event.slug)
    else: 
        form = AddVideo()
    return render(request, 'add_video.html', {'form': form})
```